# When passing a UTF8 String to RemObject (Delphi 2007) which String Type to use - Utf8String or WideString

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, remobjects

There is a Delphi 2007 Application that offers a WebService over RemObjects. I want now to pass a UTF-8 String to this application using this WebService. Now there are two String types that I could use in Delphi2007: Utf8String and WideString. (Utf8String is in Delphi 2007 equal to String - AnsiString)
[image: RemObjects - UTF8String vs WideString]
I have tried it with both but only with the Utf8String it works. Is using a Utf8String correct or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WideString` is encoded in UTF-16 in all Delphi versions. It's a wrapper around the COM `BSTR`. You simply cannot store UTF-8 content in a `WideString`.

The data type that holds UTF-8 strings in pre-Unicode Delphi is `UTF8String`, which is essentially just an `AnsiString`. It is defined like so:

```
type
  UTF8String = type string;
```

In pre-Unicode Delphi, `string` is `AnsiString`, an array of 8 bit character elements. Precisely what is needed to hold a UTF-8 payload.

In post-unicode Delphi, `UTF8String` is still an `AnsiString`, but this time with code page information.

```
type
  UTF8String = type AnsiString(65001);
```

So, in all cases, you use `UTF8String` to hold a UTF-8 encoded string.